# Diferencia entre CP-1252 y UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, codificación

Estaba yo tratando de programar y me percaté de que el documento poseía la codificación UTF-8, siguiente a eso me pregunté: ¿cual es la diferencia entre ambos?, está claro que UTF-8 tiene un par de caracteres usados más que cp-1252, sin embargo me animo a hacer esta pregunta para saber si hay alguna otra diferencia.
Gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hace muchos años atrás, las codificaciones definían un universo de hasta 256 caracteres, había alrededor de 128 (ASCII) que eran estándar en cualquier codificación (letras/números y varios símbolos) y luego había particularidades según los países o regiones que usaban el resto del universo. La codificación [**Windows-1252**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) es una de las de este tipo. No es un estándar, aunque es una codificación muy extendida, es un superconjunto de la [**ISO-8959-1**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Con el tiempo, fue claro, que 256 caracteres son insuficientes para cubrir todos los posibles usados en el mundo. Surgen entonces las codificaciones multi-byte, y el estándar [**Unicode**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), para poder ampliar el espectro.  [**UTF-8**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) es una de estas codificaciones de este tipo, es multi byte y variable, puede codificar caracteres en 1, 2, 3 y hasta 4 bytes y es consistente con la tabla ASCII estándar.

La diferencia fundamental entre ambos:

[**Windows-1252**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (uni-byte) puede codificar hasta 256 caracteres y/o códigos de control no imprimibles, [**UTF-8**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (multi-byte) por el contrario, puede codificar un número mucho más grande, en la red las estimaciones de esta cantidad es superior al millón de caracteres.

Comment: ¡Esta era la respuesta que buscaba!, gracias.